# random.choice for 2D array, bigger numbers with higher probability?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability

Is there a way to randomly pick n-items from every row in a 2D array with the higher probability picking the bigger values w/o using a LOOP

random.choice() works only for 1D array...

F.e. if i have :

```
 q = np.random.random((10,10))
```

i can pick the max-2 in every row like this :

```
  np.sort(q,axis=1)[:,-2:]
```

what I want instead is to pick randomly 2 not always the max, but with higher probability the bigger numbers..

here is how you get single row with probabilities :

```
np.random.choice(q[0,:], p=q[0,:]/q[0,:].sum())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
q = np.random.random((10,10))

def choice(row, n, replace=False):
    return np.random.choice(row, size=n, p=row/row.sum(), replace=replace)

np.apply_along_axis(func1d=choice, axis=1, arr=q, n=2)
```

I don't know what array do you have, but you should probably check that `row.sum()` is not 0 to avoid errors in computation of `p=row/row.sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

A non-numpy solution that uses [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is the following:

```
res = [random.choices(l, weights=l, k=2) for l in q]
```